# MEF under IIS is not loading parts

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I have problem with loading mef parts under iis. The load method looks like this:

```
private void LoadPlugins(string path)
{
    var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog();
    var directoryCatalogExe = new DirectoryCatalog(path, "*.exe");
    aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(directoryCatalogExe);
    var container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog);
    container.ComposeParts(this);
}
```

The method works perfectly in console application or in cassini. Under iis the parts count is 0 - no error, no exception in event log, nothing...

I have completely no idea what is going on. The path is 100% correct.

Comment: What value are you passing as 'path' to LoadPlugins?

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(configPath) where configPath looks like "~\Plugin". At the end the path = D:\TFS\Projects\WebTools\trunc\WebTools.UI.Web\Plugins

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with @stakx assesment. I use a different approach to container creation to make it more environment agnostic. I create an interface:

```
/// <summary>
/// Defines the required contract for implementing a composition container factory.
/// </summary>
public interface ICompositionContainerFactory
{
    #region Methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an instance of <see cref="CompositionContainer"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An instance of <see cref="CompositionContainer"/>.</returns>
    CompositionContainer CreateCompositionContainer();
    #endregion
}
```

With a **default** implementation (which works in console apps, service hosts):

```
public class DefaultCompositionContainerFactory : ICompositionContainerFactory
{
    #region Methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an instance of <see cref="CompositionContainer"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// An instance of <see cref="CompositionContainer"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public CompositionContainer CreateCompositionContainer()
    {
        var domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        string path = domain.BaseDirectory;

        // Use the base directory from where the application is running.
        var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(path);

        // Create the container.
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

        return container;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And a **web** specific implementation:

```
public class WebCompositionContainerFactory : ICompositionContainerFactory
{
    #region Methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an instance of <see cref="CompositionContainer"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// An instance of <see cref="CompositionContainer"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public CompositionContainer CreateCompositionContainer()
    {
        string path = HttpRuntime.BinDirectory;

        // Use the base directory from where the application is running.
        var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(path);

        // Create the container.
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

        return container;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Which I wire up through configuration.

The other thing to consider is that you are passing *.exe as your catalog filter, are you using executable assemblies in your web application?

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause of this might be a wrong value for `path`.

For example, you should not assume that the current directory will be your code's `"bin"` directory, so passing `"."` might be a bad idea.

If that is what you're doing, try specifying a path based on `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`:

```
// using System.IO;
// using System.Reflection;    

string binPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
LoadPlugins(binPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference when you are running in a console app or cassini and IIS is the security context.

When running the console app or cassini, the security context is the logged on user, which is you.

When running under IIS the security context is the identity of the application pool, which by default is NETWORK SERVICE.

It is probably that your MEF parts are in a directory that NETWORK SERVICE does not have access too.